# How to get rid of bugs in Revenant?

Tags: revenant

The old [Revenant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revenant_%28video_game%29) game had its share of bugs. Some of them were non-critical, but annoying (e.g. if you had a mana-boosting item equipped, after loading a save the mana pool state wasn't restored correctly).

However some were bad to the point of being game-breaking: namely, combos and item interactions.
There were sequences where one had to perform a combo to 'learn' it. I sometimes managed it (by accident), but most of the time the game simply didn't register them.

Is there some way to fix this problem? I haven't found any working hacks, official or unofficial fixes or patches, nothing.

Comment: Also, this question probably isn't tagged correctly. And since I can't create a new tag for the game, I went with `old-games`.

Comment: I retagged it with the game name for you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like there's any support for this game anymore.  There's also no community that is active in trying to fix the bugs, and the developers never released the source.  Some games are just buggy messes that can't be fixed.  This seems like one of them :(